# Does there exist a analogue of the stringsearch package for Data.Text instead of ByteString?

Tags: haskell

The [stringsearch](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/stringsearch/) package provides fast find/replace functionality for Haskell ByteStrings. Does there exist corresponding functionality for the text strings defined in the [Data.Text](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/text) package?

The only approaches I can see at the moment involve encoding to UTF8, using stringsearch, and then converting back---which isn't really ideal!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Efficient Boyer-Moore search for Text is implemented in the package out of the box. See the source here: http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/text/0.11.1.5/doc/html/src/Data-Text-Search.html

Access to this functionality is through the standard Text API -- `splitOn`, `breakOn`, `count`, `replace`, and `isInfixOf` in particular.

Comment: That's excellent---I'd been led astray by the analogy with ByteStrings. Thanks!